# Dynamically alter Field choices in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a field on a Model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status_field = models.NullBooleanField(blank=False,
                                          verbose_name="Status",
                                          choices=((True, 'Approved'),
                                                   (False, 'Denied'),
                                                   (None, 'Pending')))
```

I then have a ModelForm for this Model. In that ModelForm, I want to conditionally/dynamically remove one of these choices. I'm currently trying:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        if self.instance and self.instance.status_field is not None:
            self.fields['status_field'].choices.remove((None, 'Pending'))
            print self.fields['status_field'].choices
```

I can tell from the print statement that the choice is indeed removed. However, I must be missing something because when the form is rendered, the widget for this field still includes the choice I removed.

Effectively what I'm trying to do is prevent this field from becoming None/null once a value has been supplied. To make it easy for users, I'd like to just remove that option in the dropdown.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Then the form is initialized the `choices` property is copied from the field to the field's widget.  So you have to remove the choice from the widget too:

```
if self.instance and self.instance.status_field is not None:
    new_choices = list(self.fields['status_field'].choices)
    new_choices.remove((None, 'Pending'))
    self.fields['status_field'].choices = new_choices
    self.fields['status_field'].widget.choices = new_choices
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I'll give it a shot when I'm back working on this codebase tomorrow.

Comment: I'm going to leave this answer "correct" because I think it does answer the specific question I asked. However, it doesn't work as a good solution to the actual problem I'm trying to solve. Once the choice is removed, it's gone, even if you use the form on an instance where `status_field` is None.

Comment: I had to predict that, sorry.  To solve this issue you have to copy the original `choices` and remove the `Pending` status from that copy.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work too :-( I forgot to add the `list()` call which should copy the original `choices`.  See the another update.